# Get names of multiple image files to a text file

Tags: macos, file-management

I need to make an array containing over 100 different image names and I wonder if there is any way to "convert" the image names from a  folder into a .txt file using terminal to then paste them into xcode instead of manually write all of them. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to terminal and type

```
ls                   # list files
ls -lt               # list files with details
ls *.jpg             # list only jpg files
ls > files.txt       # list files and write them to files.txt
```

The # by the way, is just a comment. You can combine the above commands.

Although I need to say, that the PROPER way of doing this, is letting you code find those files in the desired directory, unless there's a good reason for not doing so.